# Is it possible to change dimension names of arrays in a list using lapply instead of for cycle?

Tags: r

I have a large list of n-dimensional arrays, all of the same dimensions.
I need to set or change the names of a particular dimension in all arrays in the list.
To illustrate this I am posing a toy example as follows:

```
a1 <- matrix(1:6, ncol = 2)
a2 <- a1*10
(l1 <- list(a1, a2))
## [[1]]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    4
## [2,]    2    5
## [3,]    3    6
## 
## [[2]]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]   10   40
## [2,]   20   50
## [3,]   30   60
```

Say, for instance, that I want to name columns as "one" and "two" in both arrays. I
know that using the **for** cycle this operation is easily done as

```
for (i in 1:length(l1)) {
   dimnames(l1[[i]])[[2]] <- c("one", "two")
}
l1
## [[1]]
##      one two
## [1,]   1   4
## [2,]   2   5
## [3,]   3   6
## 
## [[2]]
##      one two
## [1,]  10  40
## [2,]  20  50
## [3,]  30  60
```

Do you know if it is possible to have the same result using the **lapply** function on
list **l1**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` is a key.

```
l1_2 <- lapply(l1, function(x) {
  dimnames(x)[[2]] <- c("one", "two")
  return(x)
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `colnames`  of the matrix.

```
lapply(l1, function(x) {colnames(x) <- c('one', 'two');x})

#[[1]]
#     one two
#[1,]   1   4
#[2,]   2   5
#[3,]   3   6

#[[2]]
#     one two
#[1,]  10  40
#[2,]  20  50
#[3,]  30  60
```

If you have list of dataframes you can also use `setNames` :

```
lapply(l1, setNames, c('one', 'two'))
```